# adding different tableviews on a scrollview controlled by a page control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have added different tableviews on a scrollview that are controlled by a page control. I am setting them like this.

```
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
    if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageStages.count) {
        // If it's outside the range of what we have to display, then do nothing
        return;
    }
    // Load an individual page, first seeing if we've already loaded it
    UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null]) {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
        frame.size.width = 280.0f;
        frame.size.height = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height;

        frame.origin.x = (320 * page)+20;
        NSLog(@"orgin x is %d",(320 * page)+20);
        NSLog(@"orgin x is %f",frame.origin.x);
        frame.origin.y = 0;

        UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        table.delegate = self;
        table.dataSource = self;

        table.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:table];
        [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:table];
    }
}
```

Every thing is working ok. The tableviews are added and the swiping als works. The only problem is that the x-coordinate is not right. Every tableview should have a margin of 20 px on both sides. So to get my X of the next tableview I do this.

```
frame.origin.x = (320 * page)+20;
```

For the first tableview it's ok, but when I scroll to the next it everytimes goes a little bit more to the left.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

it's solved with me when i set the bounds of the table not the frame itself try to add this

```
[table setBounds:CGPointMake(x, y>)];
```